# Is it possible to stop asynctask while doInBackground running?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm creating as async task in the ActivityB Oncreate().
In that task i'm running a infinite while loop in **doInBackground()** While i'm moving to previous acitivity and comes again to the activityB, another async task got created.

**My Problem** is now two infinite while loop is running. Is it possible to stop the async task when i move to previous activity?

Comment: put ``!isCancelled()`` in your loop condition

then call ``asyncTask.cancel(boolean); ``

Comment: Where i need to call asyncTask.cancel(boolean);? OnBackPressed function?

Comment: Thanks a lot Trafalgar, its working awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure... check out [isCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29):

```
public Void doInBackground( .... ) {

   while( !isCancelled() ) {
       ...endless activity...
   }

   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `Cancel()` method , but calling **`cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)`** doesn't necessarily stop the execution of the background process.

All that usually happens is that the AsyncTask will execute onCancelled(), and won't run onPostExecute() when it completes.

See the docs ('Canceling an async task' section)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

I'd review your app's design and re work it so that this condition does not arise rather than try to cancel running Async tasks.