# Cancelling/stopping asynchtask running endless code

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a metronome, using example classes found here http://masterex.github.io/archive/2012/05/28/android-audio-synthesis.html

I've built an activity with a couple buttons to start, and stop the metronome.
The play() method (generates, saves and plays a sample) uses a do{}(while) on boolean value play, which should be set to false when the stop() method is called.

Initially, i found the UI jammed pressing play, so decided to run the play() method in an asynchtask, however i still had issues stopping it. I looked up a similar issue here, [Is it possible to stop asynctask while doInBackground running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698008/is-it-possible-to-stop-asynctask-while-doinbackground-running) and tried to adjust the while loop to check isCancelled, while calling cancel() in the stop() method (and in the stop button listener) but still no joy.

I don't see how this solution could work at all since neither the loop in the solution, or the metronome's play() ever allows doinbackground return anything

> "Calling this method (cancel()) will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. "

Any ideas how this could be better implemented to allow the execution of play() to run and stop with button presses.

My runinbackground, scooped the contents of play() and put it in here, in my activity thread  i'm creating a metronome m, then calling m.execute to start, and m.cancel to stop.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        calcSilence();
        double[] tick =
                soundGen.getSineWave(this.tick, 8000, beatSound);
        double[] tock =
                soundGen.getSineWave(this.tick, 8000, sound);
        double silence = 0;
        double[] sound = new double[8000];
        int t = 0,s = 0,b = 0;

       while(!isCancelled()){           
                for(int i=0;i<sound.length&&play;i++) {
                        if(t<this.tick) {
                                if(b == 0)
                                        sound[i] = tock[t];
                                else
                                        sound[i] = tick[t];
                                t++;
                        } else {
                                sound[i] = silence;
                                s++;
                                if(s >= this.silence) {
                                        t = 0;
                                        s = 0;
                                        b++;
                                        if(b > (this.beat-1))
                                                b = 0;
                                }
                        }
                }                  
                soundGen.writeSound(sound);

        } 
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any lock downs with your UI thread while you play a sound in async task. Are you sure you are playing the sound in background? You need to show some code so we can detect the problem.

Comment: The problem is in the asynctask though. You need to post that code. Your do loop should just continue `while(play && !isCancelled())` that should work fine